# Ошибка размещения файлов

Tags: php

Ошибка:

> Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(`/home/dax/s/t/e/commerce/public_html/sindikat.php`) is not within the allowed path(s): (`/nonexistent`) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '`/home/dax/s/t/e/steamcommerce/public_html/sindikat.php`' (`include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear'`) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Посмотрите параметр DocumentRoot в настройках сервера, правильно ли там указан путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл **sindikat.php** не найден видимо, проверьте или скиньте код

Comment: в том то и дело что кода нет. Это пустой пхп файл. И его невозможно открыть. Даже права доступа стоят 777. Все равно 0

Answer (score 1):

Как можно программировать, не зная базы английского языка !?
Ведь ошибка четко гласит, что невозможно открыть файл, значит его либо нет,проверьте(регистр букв имеет значение!), либо его не разрешено открывать конфигурацией сервера.

Comment: А вообще, каким образом вы пытаетесь получить доступ к файлу, покажите =)

Comment: Ахахахаххаха типо я его своими глазами вижу а его там нет! Это как так? простым образом *****.ru/sindikat.php

Comment: я сам его заливаю

Comment: Ничего просто так не бывает. Покажите, каким образом вы пытаетесь получить доступ к файлу, возможно, ошибка именно там =)

Comment: Я же написал! Через доменное имя sssssss.ru/sindikat.php

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли, покажите непосредственный PHP код.

Comment: Этот файл пуст! Нет в нем php кода. Есть сайт и 1 файл. И этот единственный файл не могу открыть.

Comment: Нет, вы снова не поняли, меня не интересует содержимое того файла, меня интересует метод PHP, которым вы обращаетесь к этому файлу.
Include(filename), например.

Comment: Не знаю этого. Но проблему решил.))))

Comment: Молодец! Так в чем была проблема?

Comment: Доходило долго до хоста, просто подождал 15 минут. А плс поясни как определять метод PHP, которым вы обращаетесь к этому файлу.

Comment: Ну здесь есть четыре метода, с одинаковым значением, отличаются они друг от друга, тем, что будет, если файл не удалось подключить и сколько раз его можно подключать. Самый важный метод - include(filename), где filename - полное имя к файлу. Данный метод просто вставляет весь код(PHP,HTML и т.д) в то место, где его вызвали. Понятно?